# Reset innerHTML w/o reloading page

Tags: javascript, forms, function, reset

I have written a little personality quiz. Once you selected the answers from a pull down menu and submitted the form (`id="quizgenerator`), the form itself is replaced by the result with the help of the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById('quizgenerator').innerHTML = "<p id='result'  
align='center'><b>" + result + "</b></p>";
```

So far, so good. Now to the tricky part I can't figure out: I want people to be able to "go back" to the form and take the quiz again, changing their answers and resubmitting to see what result they may end up then WITHOUT reloading the page.

I can't add a reset button to the form, as the form is replaced by the result. So for now I added a reset button outside the form:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" id="submit" onClick="history.go(0);">
```

This works, but it reloads the page. Is there a way to reset the innerHTML part without reloading?

I already searched the web for answers but in all those cases the reset button was always part of the form.

Comment: rather than replace the html, just hide/show two different divs. one containing the form and one containing the result.

Comment: Do you just want to erase what is in the form fields and then show the form again, or do you want a "sticky" form that retains what has already been entered in the form fields and then shows the form again?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple code illustrating my comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bk8rH/

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function () {
    $("#myform").hide();
    $("#myresults").text($("#mytext").val());
    $("#myresultsWrap").show();
});
$("#toform").click(function () {
    $("#myresultsWrap").hide();
    $("#myform").show();
});
```

of course you could make it fancier, add in your own data, maybe clear the form if users go back to it, etc. but this should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This makes sense to me. However, I must be doing something wrong as it doesn't work for me. I saw that jQuery 1.9.1 was used for your example to work. So I added `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>` to the head of the file. But no luck. Can you give me another hint here. Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: its hard to say without knowing your context... do you have the code within a document ready block?

Answer (score 0):

You can't revert to a previous HTML state without reloading. What you can do however is the same thing you do when you replace the form. Only this time you replace the result with the original form. You could choose to add the same form code again in that part of the code, or you could save the innerHTML of the quizgenerator element, save it in a variable and place it back when you want to 'reset'.